# Why are my strokes showing up black, with no colour selected?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, creative-cloud, line-art, black

All of my strokes are coming with a random black 1pt stroke that I can't edit or get rid of. I can change the colour of the 'outer' stroke, which is technically the same line. That shouldn't be possible. I'm not new to Illustrator but just recently purchased CC, is this usual in CC? Quite frustrating. Please help. Here's some pictures. [image: Stroke seleceted with no fill, yet it's still showing black]

[image: Now I've added colour to the stroke, but the black 1pt line still shows]

Comment: I put all of the art effected on a new layer and deleted that layer. Seemed to have worked. Something must have bugged out on that old layer.

Comment: Can you check the Appearance Panel and double check that no effects or additions strokes are added ?

Answer (score 3):

The little **solid circle** next the to the *red box on the right* indicates the *layer* has some **Appearance attributes** applied to it.

[image]

Most likely a stroke is applied to the layer via the **Appearance Panel**. Remove that.